# Find a function module by its name?

Tags: python, r

Is there any module/function in **python** that can search functions by context or by name in python modules.

The R equivalent, if `findFn` from the `sos` package is very useful, to Search in contributed R packages.

```
 library(sos)
 findFn('some words defintions')      ## find a package that contain such definition
 findFn('some_function_name')   ## find the some_function_name package
```

For example:

```
 findFn('Connect oracle')
```

will redirect you to a link which suggest to use the `ROracle` package.

Comment: If you already know the module in which you want to search a function, maybe you could scan the `__dict__` of that module.

Comment: @Hyperboreus thanks. but Now I don't know the module. I think I would use `dir`  in that case isn't it ?

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit how `findFn` does its lookup. Does it search all imported libraries? All libraries on the path? (For non-R-users)

Comment: @Hyperboreus `findFn` searches CRAN. an equivalent would be something that searches all of PyPI. I don't think such a module exists.

Comment: How about [`pypi-tools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypi-tools/0.0.2)?

Comment: @agstudy I think the short answer to this is no... unless you want to manually iterate over _all_ of the modules and then call `dir()` on that _entire_ module and its submodules and then search in _all_ those results for that module... uggh. (That is, with the default libraries).

Comment: @jbaums pypi-tools looks like a good condidate even it don't give always the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

U can use 'eval'

```
FunctioNameAsString = test
FunctionArgumentsAsString = ''

eval('self.'+FunctioNameAsString+'()')
```

=

```
self.test()
```

or

```
eval('self.__class__.'+FunctioNameAsString+'()')
```

=

```
self.__class__.test()
```